# Update Text with Dissmissble setState

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to update my `Text()` value whenever I dismiss an item from the screen .

This is the `MainScreen()` :

```
Text.rich(
              
                  TextSpan(
                    text: total().toString() + " DT",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 16,
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
```

The function `total()` is located in `Product Class` like this :

```
    class Product {
  final int? id;
  final String? nameProd;
  final String? image;
  final double? price;

  Product({this.id, this.nameProd, this.image, this.price});
}

List<Product> ListProduitss = [
  Product(
      price: 100, nameProd: 'Produit1', image: 'assets/images/freedomlogo.png')
];

double total() {
  double total = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < ListProduitss.length; i++) {
    total += ListProduitss[i].price!;
  }
  print(total);
  return total;
}
```

I have this in the main screen .
After I remove the item from list , I want to reupdate the `Text()` because the function is printing a new value in console everytime I dismiss a product :

This is from statefulWidget `CartItem()` that I render inside `MainScreen()` :

```
 ListView.builder(
    itemCount: ListProduitss.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) => Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
      child: Dismissible(
        key: Key(ListProduitss.toString()),
        direction: DismissDirection.endToStart,
        onDismissed: (direction) {
          setState(() {
            ListProduitss.removeAt(index);
             total();
           // What to add here to update Text() value everytime
          });
        },
```

I tried to refresh the main screen but It didn't work .

```
onDismissed: (direction) {
          setState(() {
            ListProduitss.removeAt(index);
           MainScreen();
          });
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to declare a local string variable to use within the text. Then initialise the variable using total() within initState(). Then in setState do the same process.

However, it may be beneficial for you to look into a state management pattern such as BLoC pattern. https://bloclibrary.dev/#/

```
late String text;

void initState() {
    super.initState();

    text = Product.total();
  }

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      extendBody: true,
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Text(text),
          ElevatedButton(child: Text("Update"), onPressed:() => setState(() {
            text = Product.total();
          }),)
        ],
      )
    );
  }
```

I am going to add another example as there was confusion to the above example. Below is an example of updated a text field with the length of the list. It is updated every time an item is removed.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text(_title)),
        body: const MyStatefulWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyStatefulWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyStatefulWidget> createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  List<int> items = List<int>.generate(100, (int index) => index);
  late String text;

  @override
  void initState() {
    text = items.length.toString(); // << this is total;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Text(text),
        Expanded(
          child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: items.length,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16),
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return Dismissible(
                background: Container(
                  color: Colors.green,
                ),
                key: ValueKey<int>(items[index]),
                onDismissed: (DismissDirection direction) {
                  setState(() {
                    items.removeAt(index);
                    text = items.length.toString(); // < this is total()
                  });
                },
                child: ListTile(
                  title: Text(
                    'Item ${items[index]}',
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you , but I don't want a button to update the text. I want to update it whenever I dismiss a product.

Comment: The button is just an example of setting the text to the new value returned by your total function. You would place this within the onDismissed() body.

Comment: they are not on same Widget so I can't do that.